# How can I make my Discord bot (Javascript) answer a random number to a specific question an user asks?

Tags: javascript, discord

[The code I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDhKj.png)

I am using this code, and when the question is asked (in a different language :D ,sorry!) the same answer is given, when I restart the bot and ask the again question it's a different generated number, but when I ask the question again (without restarting the bot) it repeats the answer it gave after restart.
It's basically only generating a new random number every time the bot turns on..

Comment: Move the Randomnumber inside the bot.on function. At the moment the random number is generated once and being used in every message as oppose to generating a random number on each message.

Comment: Check the answer, let me know if you still need help :)

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked just fine! <3

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here you go

```
bot.on('message', message => {
       var Randomnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1);
       
       .... rest of your code goes here
    });
```

Comment: @Gabriel Gogishvili Can you accept it as the answer please :)